# shoulda gem allow_value method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

**old_spec.rb**

```
it { should allow_value(:nil).for(:invoice_type) }
it { should allow_value(:customer_invoice).for(:invoice_type) }
it { should allow_value(:creative_invoice).for(:invoice_type) }
it { should_not allow_value(:other).for(:invoice_type) }
```

I have these code in my spec file and I convert them like below.

**new_spec.rb**

```
   it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:invoice_type).in_array(
     [:nil,:customer_invoice,:creative_invoice]) }
```

I wonder that in the second file (new_spec.rb) do I have to write this line.

```
it { should_not allow_value(:other).for(:invoice_type) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of how `ensure_inclusion_of` works, you shouldn't need to explicitly prevent other values.

Of course, it would be very easy to check this for yourself...